# How can I stop IntelliJ from putting parameters on their own line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I just wrote this line:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(actualReader);
```

and the automatic reformatter gave me:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>
                (actualReader);
```

I think this looks extremely strange and I want to tell IntelliJ to never put parameters on a line of their own. I'd like:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(
                actualReader);
```

or better yet:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = 
       new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(actualReader);
```

I'm looking through the project settings under Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces but I'm not sure what option I should change. I don't want to always have a new line after '(', I just want to make sure that IntelliJ never breaks there when it breaks multiline statements. I don't see any other options I could change.

Can this be done?

EDIT: If anyone wants to test on their own IntelliJ, I have my margins set to 120 characters, and the exact line (with the correct amount of whitespace -- 8 spaces) is:

```
        HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(actualReader)
```

Comment: Good question, following.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The setting that is causing the wrapping to occur is *Code Style > Java > [Wrapping and Braces] > "Method call arguments"*. You can set to "Do not wrap" if you do not want it wrapped. For wrapping, set to "Wrap if Long" or "Chop down if long".  Watch the `foo1` method in the sample code to see the difference between wrap and chop.

**Wrap:**

```
wrapped(
    0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053,
    0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056,
    0x0057);
```

**Chop:**

```
chopped(
    0x0051, 
    0x0052,
    0x0053,
    0x0054, 
    0x0055, 
    0x0056,
    0x0057);
```

To get your first choice, such that the '(' is kept with the method call (or constructor call in this case), set the "new line after '('" option. That will give you:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(
        actualReader);
```

To get your second "or better yet" option, set *Code Style > Java > [Wrapping and Braces] > "Assignment Statements"* to "Wrap if long", "Chop if long" or "Wrap always". Set to "Wrap if long" you will get:

```
HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<WritableDataPoint> actualBridgeBuilder = 
        new HDF5CompoundDSBridgeBuilder<>(actualReader);
```

Comment: I was checking the options under the "Method declaration parameters" block but it had not occurred to me that the block itself was also configurable. This is exactly what I was looking for and has instantly cleared my headache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, because I've never seen IntelliJ do what you're describing.

My IntelliJ 13.1.1 does not put parameters on a new line.  When I look at Code Style->Java under Method call arguments, all the boxes are unchecked.  See if yours are, too.

Comment: I only have "Align when multiline" checked. Unchecking it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is the right margin set to under 'General'?  Mine is 120 chars.

Comment: 120 chars -- see my edit for the text with the right amount of whitespace, which you can try on your IntelliJ if you want.